# Getting the first elements per row in an array in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

Let's say i have an array of Tuples, s,  in the form of:

```
s = ((1, 23, 34),(2, 34, 44), (3, 444, 234))
```

and i want to return another Tuple, t, consisting of the first element per row:

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
```

Which would be the most efficient method to do this? I could of course just iterate through s, but is there any slicker way of doing it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No.

```
t = tuple(x[0] for x in s)
```

Answer (score 5):

The list comprehension method given by Ignacio is the cleanest.

Just for kicks, you could also do:

```
zip(*s)[0]
```

`*s` expands `s` into a list of arguments. So it is equivalent to

```
zip( (1, 23, 34),(2, 34, 44), (3, 444, 234))
```

And `zip` returns  `n` tuples where each tuple contains the `nth` item from each list.

Comment: Actually, that's a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
s = ((1, 23, 34),(2, 34, 44), (3, 444, 234))
print(next(itertools.izip(*s)))
```

`itertools.izip` returns an iterator. The `next` function returns the next (and in this case, first) element from the iterator.

In Python 2.x, `zip` returns a tuple.
`izip` uses less memory since iterators do not generate their contents until needed.

In Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator.