# How do I access the 1st element of each list in a lists of lists

Tags: python

Example:

```
numbers = ['1','2','3']
letters = ['a','b','c']
```

I want to get [1,a] as a results. Yeah I can loop through it, but I'm wondering if there is a fast one line way of doing this.

EDIT EDIT !!!!

I made a horrible mistake in describing the problem.

I have access to the combined list (the list of lists of the question):

```
list_of_lists = [ numbers, letters]
```

which is equal to:

```
[ ['1','2','3'],['a','b','c']]
```

Sorry for the confusion. The end result is still the same, this would be ['1','a'].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054416/getting-the-first-elements-per-row-in-an-array-in-python.  Someone else asked for the answer to the same homework problem before you.

Comment: Is your question related to some bigger context, if so please elaborate us. Just commented because you are refering to looping, but clearly the solution you are looking for doesen't need any looping, thanks

Comment: OK took me forever to find the add comment. Well I've looked at the homework and that's exactly how I should do it. I'm using the solution to grab the description names from a MySQL description query. You know, cause they decided that the attributes should be part of it too.

Answer (score 7):

Try a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
# (numbers, letters) can be replaced with `list_of_lists` 
>>> [ x[0] for x in (numbers, letters) ] 
['1', 'a']
```

Comment: Why upvoted? Clearly OP's question (as stated now) has a constant time solution. Or is your answer some kind of joke? thanks

Comment: @eat: No, no joke, just the an answer, that worked with the previous version of the question (and still works). Besides, it's in the same complexity class as your answer.

Comment: @The MYYN OK, then perhaps I'll misunderstod something. Do you consider my answer giving wrong solution? Why list comprehension seems to be the right answer? Clearly no iterations needed. I'm just concernd because I felt that OP was looking for something not stated in the question yet ;-).

Comment: @eat: No, your answer is fine. I would have upvoted it, if it just said `[ list_of_list[0][0], list_of_list[1][0] ]`, but the rest is a bit noisy (at the moment). To me, list comprehension looks a bit cleaner (and it is actually shorter).

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator
map(operator.itemgetter(0), [numbers, letters])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_lists = [['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
list_of_firsts = [l[0] for l in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score -1):

I would try:

```
zip(*list_of_lists)[0]
```

Comment: At least go for `itertools.izip(*list_of_lists).next()`. Your solution loops through the entire lists.