# List a specific position in each list within a list (python)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, matrix, position

Is there a way to select every 2nd or 3rd (for example) item within a matrix?

For example:

```
f = [["1", "5", "8", "9"], ["2", "6", "9", "10"], ["3", "7", "11", "12"]]
```

I am wondering if there is a direct function to select every 2nd number in every list (preferably putting those digits in a list as well). Thus resulting into:

```
["5", "6", "7"]
```

*I know that I can achieve this using a loop* but I am wondering if I can achieve this directly.

Comment: There is already an answer for tuples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054416/getting-the-first-elements-per-row-in-an-array-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any loop (external)

```
>>> f = [["1", "5", "8", "9"], ["2", "6", "9", "10"], ["3", "7", "11", "12"]]
>>> list(map(lambda x:x[1],f))  # In python2, The list call is not required
['5', '6', '7']
```

Ref : [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Another way to do it without loop (Courtesy : [Steven Rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750063/list-a-specific-position-in-each-list-within-a-list-python/28750100#comment45782517_28750100))

```
>>> import operator
>>> list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), f))
['5', '6', '7']
```

Ref: [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Yet another way to do it without loop (Courtesy : [Kasra A D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750063/list-a-specific-position-in-each-list-within-a-list-python/28750100?noredirect=1#comment45782817_28750100))

```
>>> list(zip(*f)[1])
['5', '6', '7']
```

Ref: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Just Note: A list comp is more pythonic in a few cases, though not in most cases ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/4099593 ... However as you mention *I know that I can achieve this using a loop but I am wondering if I can achieve this directly.* `map` is the only way you can do to get your job done without using any loop!

Comment: Agreed.  A list comp is best.  Also an available option `list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), f))`.  If using Python 2 the call to `list()` can be omitted.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yep, But I always insist on having the `list` call, just in case a future user tries this!

Comment: you can add `zip` to collection of solutions ;) : `>>> zip(*f)[1]
('5', '6', '7')
`

Answer (score 5):

Try [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
seconds = [x[1] for x in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use list comprehension:

```
i = 1  # Index of list to be accessed
sec = [s[i] for s in f if len(s) > i]
```

This code will also check in each sublist whether the index is a valid value or not.