# creating new tuple with index i from each list of list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have below list of list called mylist and I want to take first element from each list and create a tuple. I want to do this for all n elements from list of list.

```
mylist = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [5, 8, 10], [100, 200, 30]]
```

convert to

```
mytuple = ((1,'a', 5, 100) ,(2,'b', 8, 200), (3,'c',10, 30))
```

I have managed to do it with below steps and I am sure there is better way :)

```
i = 0;
while(i < n):
    templist = (x[i] for x in mylist)
    newlist.append(tuple(templist))
    i += 1
ftuple = tuple(newlist)
```

I have seen this link but haven't been able to find easier way looking at it
[SOlink1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054416/getting-the-first-elements-per-row-in-an-array-in-python) [Solink2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750063/list-a-specific-position-in-each-list-within-a-list-python?lq=1)

Comment: Both of those links have exactly the solutions you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions#zip) is what you need:

```
>>> mylist = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [5, 8, 10], [100, 200, 30]]
>>> zip(*mylist)  # In Python 3.x, this returns an iterator instead of a list
[(1, 'a', 5, 100), (2, 'b', 8, 200), (3, 'c', 10, 30)]
>>> tuple(zip(*mylist))
((1, 'a', 5, 100), (2, 'b', 8, 200), (3, 'c', 10, 30))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - appreciate it !!

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas data frame for this.

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [5, 8, 10], [100, 200, 30]]

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist).transpose()

print(df.values)
array([[1, 'a', 5, 100],
       [2, 'b', 8, 200],
       [3, 'c', 10, 30]], dtype=object)
```

For solution in the exact same form:

```
tuple([tuple(row) for row in df.values])
((1, 'a', 5, 100), (2, 'b', 8, 200), (3, 'c', 10, 30))
```